# Why is the texture all wrong on my model?

Tags: textures, lwjgl

[image]

Why is this happening? If possible I'd like to know what this particular problem is called. The model is a simple cube made in blender and exported with normals and MTL. Texture is the cube unwrapped with crate image on each side.

Are the UV coordinates wrong?

Comment: The UV-coordinates look like they're off.

Comment: "Why is the texture wrong?" will always be "because the UVs are wrong."

Comment: What have you tried to solve it, what have you researched, and what were the results? This will make people better able to help you, and more motivated to try to help you if they feel that you've actually made an effort to solve this by yourself.

Comment: do tutorial on uvmapping

Comment: @Draco18s Not always, a texture with a side length that's not a power of 2 could also cause problems. Not in this case though, here the UVs are obviously wrong

Comment: @Bálint That's a possibility, I'll concede that point. But I would probably still assume the UVs and check those first, unless I know one texture works and another doesn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure either the parser is wrong (please post the code) or the model was exported with smooth normals

Comment: Are you sharing the vertices on the corners of the cube? (I'm just working this out in my head so might have this wrong but...) If so, given appropriate UVs you may get the right mapping for _four_ of the faces, but the UVs for the end surfaces will give you the result you're seeing. You'll probably need to make those end squares use their own set of vertices.